# Multiple time series plot in R, ggplot2,

Tags: r, ggplot2

When my date variable `YEAR` is in the fiscal years like `2010/11`, `2011/12`, `2012/13`, etc. `YEAR` is the factor variable, `variable` is character variable and `value` is numeric variable

R gives me an error message:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

My code looks like this:

after loading data and the required packages:

```
data<-mutate(data,pcosr=Internal_Revenue/Total_Income*100,
pcgrants=Grants/Total_Income*100)
data<-data %>%
select(YEAR,pcosr, pcgrants,Local_Bodies) %>% 
gather(key="variable",value="value",-YEAR, -Local_Bodies)
data<-subset(data,Local_Bodies=="vdc")

ggplot(data,aes(x=YEAR,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_line()+
labs( y="Percentage", 
color=NULL) +  # title and caption
scale_color_manual(labels = c("percentage OSR", "percentage Grants"), 
values = c("percentage OSR"="#00ba38", 
"percentage Grant"="#f8766d")) +  # line color
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5, size = 8),  # rotate 
x axis text
panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  # turn off minor grid
```

Comment: Can you please review how to post a reproducible question

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reformat your question, this way we can address you a better solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is **minimal** (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), **complete** (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and **verifiable** (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). This will help the Stack Overflow community by clarifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You provide the `fill` aesthetic but geom_line requires `color`.

It should be

```
data<-mutate(data,pcosr=Internal_Revenue/Total_Income*100,
             pcgrants=Grants/Total_Income*100)
data<-data %>%
  select(YEAR,pcosr, pcgrants,Local_Bodies) %>% 
  gather(key="variable",value="value",-YEAR, -Local_Bodies)
data<-subset(data,Local_Bodies=="vdc")

ggplot(data,aes(x=YEAR,y=value,color=variable))+geom_line()+
  labs( y="Percentage", 
        color=NULL) +  # title and caption
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("percentage OSR", "percentage Grants"), 
                     values = c("percentage OSR"="#00ba38", 
                                "percentage Grant"="#f8766d")) +  # line color
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust=0.5, size = 8),  # rotate 
        x axis text
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  # turn off minor grid
```

Comment: Dear Juergen, my code did not work even changing the aesthetcis to color. Is if due to the  date variable (YEAR)  which is could not assign as.Date.

Comment: In that case you need to provide a sample dataset.